# SimpleSchema insert fails with unhelpful error unless {validate: false} is set

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

At this point I've actually pared down my code to mimic the [example in the docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core#attaching-a-schema-to-a-collection), and I'm getting the same error.

I've defined my Collection as such:

```
var Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');

const CategorySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 255,
        optional: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Category Created",
        autoValue: () => {
            if(this.isInsert){
                return new Date();
            } else if (this.isUpsert) {
                return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
            }
        }
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Category Modified",
        autoValue: () => {
            if(this.isUpdate){
                return new Date();
            }
        },
        optional: true
    }
});

Categories.attachSchema(CategorySchema);

export { Categories };
```

[The autovalue stuff is borrowed straight from the docs.](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#autovalue)

And have a method for calling insert:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'categories.insert'(title){
        check(title, String);

        Categories.insert({title: title}, (err, res) => {
            if(err){
                console.error("Category insert failed: " + err);
            }
        });
    },
...
```

As I've tried to get through this issue, I've added and removed rules to the schema definition, sometimes getting a `call stack exceeded` error. Mostly what I get is the following:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'categories.insert' TypeError: func is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=fefb674368e70344875cb9448e3ea784a880ffb0:13027:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at doValidation (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=fefb674368e70344875cb9448e3ea784a880ffb0:13026:17)
    at ValidationContext.validate (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=fefb674368e70344875cb9448e3ea784a880ffb0:12580:57)
    at ns.Collection.doValidate (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=0564817159bbe9f8209b6a192a1fa2b2bbab924a:466:33)
    at ns.Collection.Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=0564817159bbe9f8209b6a192a1fa2b2bbab924a:260:25)
    at ns.Collection.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/matb33_collection-hooks.js?hash=d44fd0eb02806747e1bb0bdc3938463e415c63ec:402:19)
    at ns.Collection.collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (http://localhost:3000/packages/matb33_collection-hooks.js?hash=d44fd0eb02806747e1bb0bdc3938463e415c63ec:155:21)
    at DDPCommon.MethodInvocation.categories.insert (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=580bf82f2f196202280f32cf5ffacbc930cd6b10:20073:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=c9ca22092a3137a7096e8ab722ba5ab8eedb9aec:4076:25 TypeError: func is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=fefb674368e70344875cb9448e3ea784a880ffb0:13027:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at doValidation (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=fefb674368e70344875cb9448e3ea784a880ffb0:13026:17)
    at ValidationContext.validate (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=fefb674368e70344875cb9448e3ea784a880ffb0:12580:57)
    at ns.Collection.doValidate (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=0564817159bbe9f8209b6a192a1fa2b2bbab924a:466:33)
    at ns.Collection.Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=0564817159bbe9f8209b6a192a1fa2b2bbab924a:260:25)
    at ns.Collection.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/matb33_collection-hooks.js?hash=d44fd0eb02806747e1bb0bdc3938463e415c63ec:402:19)
    at ns.Collection.collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (http://localhost:3000/packages/matb33_collection-hooks.js?hash=d44fd0eb02806747e1bb0bdc3938463e415c63ec:155:21)
    at DDPCommon.MethodInvocation.categories.insert (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=580bf82f2f196202280f32cf5ffacbc930cd6b10:20073:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=c9ca22092a3137a7096e8ab722ba5ab8eedb9aec:4076:25
meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:930 Error invoking Method 'categories.insert': Internal server error [500]
```

***EDIT***

After swapping out the arrow functions:

methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    // Settings: create new category
    'categories.insert': function(title){
        check(title, String);

        Categories.insert({title: title}, function(err, res){
            if(err){
                console.error("Category insert failed: " + err);
            }
        });
    },
...
```

settings.js

```
Template.settings.onCreated(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('categories');
});

Template.settings.helpers({
    categories: function(){
        return Categories.find();
    }
});

Template.settings.events({
    'click #newCategoryButton': function(e){
        let title = $("#newCategoryInput").val();
        if(title !== ""){
            Meteor.call('categories.insert', title);
            $("#newCategoryInput").val("").focus();
        }
    },
    'click .removeCategory': function(e){
        var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
        Meteor.call('categories.remove', id);
    }
});
```

Categories.js

```
var Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories', options);

const CategorySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 255,
        optional: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Category Created",
        autoValue: function(){
            if(this.isInsert){
                return new Date();
            } else if (this.isUpsert) {
                return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
            }
        }
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Category Modified",
        autoValue: function(){
            if(this.isUpdate){
                return new Date();
            }
        },
        optional: true
    }
});

Categories.attachSchema(CategorySchema);
```

Still getting the same error as in original post

Comment: Try replacing your arrow functions with normal function declarations - see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You're using arrow functions like Sean mentioned in the comment. Replace them with traditional `function(){...}` and you should be good to go.

You can read more about this issue [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/562)

Comment: I was really hoping this would work, but no luck. I eliminated the arrow functions, even replaced the es6 syntax for funcitons in objects with the word 'function'. Same error. :(

Comment: Okay, can you update your original question with the variations that you've tried?

Comment: Edited code is above. Is it possible that I have to write my own validations?